# Using variable in setattribute function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, dom-events

Displaying NoN instead of city name. I have tried following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript" >
function submitcity(c){
document.getElementById("ct").setAttribute('value',+c);//displaying NoN
//document.cityform.submit();
alert(c);
}</script>
```

In body:

```
<img src="images/reset.jpg" width="80" height="24" onclick="submitcity('bhopal');" />
<form  action="" method="post" name="cityform" style="display:none;">
<input type="hidden" name="city" id="ct" value="" /></form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
+c
```

Putting a `+` before a value will attempt to cast it as a number. You're not passing a number. What you're infact seeing is `NaN`.

Remove the `+` from behind your variable.

```
document.getElementById("ct").setAttribute('value',+c);
```

becomes

```
document.getElementById("ct").setAttribute('value',c);
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the unary plus from `+c`

`document.getElementById("ct").setAttribute('value',+c);`

You are trying to type cast string (which doesnt represent a number) to numeric value prefixing it with `+` and hence seeing `NaN` (Not a Number), it should be:

```
document.getElementById("ct").setAttribute('value',c);
```

`+` is a unary operator used for type casting to numeric value.

See **[Unary Plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)**

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already. For example, y = +x takes the value of x and assigns that to y; that is, if x were 3, y would get the value 3 and x would retain the value 3; but if x were the string "3", y would also get the value 3. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats, as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported. Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCGeP/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function submitcity(c){
   document.getElementById("ct").setAttribute('value',c);//remove + sign before c
   //document.cityform.submit();
   alert(c);
}
```